# How to use Vue Custom Directives with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am trying to understand how to convert the example below using typescript and the Composition API, with the setup script. This example it from the [vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/custom-directives.html#introduction). I don't know what type to give the "el" parameter to get this to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue 3, components are no longer limited to only 1 root element. Implicitly, this means you no longer have an `this.$el`. You can create one by adding `ref=""` to DOM element you want to target.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
// enables v-focus in templates
const root = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
    // here you got root $el
    root.value.focus()
})

// Using Option API. I didn't check are it works.
this.$refs.$el
</script>

<template>
  <input ref="root" />
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works using Javascript but doesn't work using Typescript. The "el" parameter in that function asks for a type. Which I don't know how to satisfy.

Comment: Turn of ESLint and it won't ask. You can always type it as any.

Comment: @EthanFranson Wrote another option how to get `$el`.